# A more object oriented Angular 1.5+ component

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't use Angular 2 where I am, but I like how it's more object oriented (components are classes). We are starting to use Angular 1.5+ components and to eventually ease transition I was looking at using the new javascript functionality of classes to make components classes with Angular 1.5+. Partially just messing around here as well to see what I can come up with.

The specific question I have is that when I define $onInit by setting it to a class function it doesn't get called but when I define it as an anonymous function it does and I'm not 100% sure why. Any help would be great. A generic question would be does anyone have ideas around how to do this simulation of app.component() to javascript class?

```
class Component {
    constructor(name, templateUrl, bindings, controllerAs) {
        app.component(name, {
            templateUrl: templateUrl,
            bindings: bindings,
            controllerAs: controllerAs,
            controller: this.controller
        });
    }

    controller() {
        console.log("Inside Component controller");
    }
}

class ListNames extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super("listNames", "ListNames.html", { names: '<' }, "lstNames");
    }

    onInit() {
        console.log("onInit called");
    }

    // overrided method
    controller() {
        console.log("ListNames controller()");
        /*this.$onInit = function () {
            console.log("onInit called");
        }*/
        this.$onInit = this.onInit; // <-- this doesn't work but the above does
    }
}

lstNames = new ListNames();
```

Comment: You can't use class methods as constructors, i.e. this `this.controller` will not work.

Comment: That's what is odd. using this.controller actually does seem to work. It calls my subclasses controller function. But it doesn't work for the $onInit. However setting $onInit the the anonymous  function in the controller() subclasses controller() does work.

Comment: Setting `$onInit` to the anonymous function in the `controller()` subclasses controller() does work because the `controller` of your component is the `controller` function, not the entire class.